# MenuItem Shortcut Key in Middle of text

Tags: wpf, menuitem

How to assign shortcut alt-key to a menuitem when the key is the middle of the text.

something like this

```
Modify = alt+O = M_odify
```

This is good but I dont want to display the underscore in the user..

Comment: What's the point of having unknown shortcuts?

Comment: We're just following the requirements... it's just.. they are used to it in their previous system..

Comment: You better beat that out of them somehow...